# Recorrer una matriz a través de un ciclo for y generar columnas por cada elemento de esa matriz

Tags: python, funciones, matrices, pandas, numpy

Soy muy novata con python y estoy realizando un ejercicio relacionado con spotify. Para este punto particular,

- Necesito generar una columna por cada "pais" de la matriz "countries" a través de una función. La idea es ver la lista de canciones Top por cada país (de un BD de spotify)...
- Luego hacer una correlación entre países para ver en porcentajes si hay coincidencias (por ejemplo: saber qué porcentaje de correlación hay entre Argentina y España de las 5 canciones top). Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.

este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#read csv
sp=pd.read_csv('../data.csv', sep=',')

sp.columns=['position','track_name','artist','streams','url','date','region']  #renombro columnas por comodidad 
paises={'es':'España','it':'Italia','cy':'Cipre','ar':'Argentina'} ##completar el diccionario


def Top(df, top, country, date):
    df=df[df.region==country]
    df=df[df.position<=top]
    df=df[df.date==date]   
    return df 

song='Chantaje'
top=10
country='es'
date= '2017-08-01' 

#print(Top(sp , top , country, '2017-08-01'))

top_es = Top(sp , top , country, '2017-08-01')
top_es = top_es.track_name
#print(top_es.track_name)

top_es = top_es.to_frame()
top_es.columns = [country]
print(top_es)

#crear 1ero esta funcion. Luego crear un lista con los nombres de los paises.
def TopCountry(df, top, country, date):
    top_c= Top(df, top, country, date)
    top_c= top_c.track_name
    top_c= top_c.to_frame()
    top_c.columns=[country]
    return top_c

countries=["us", "gb", "ad", "ar", "at", "au", "be", "bg",
               "bo", "br", "ca", "ch", "cl", "co", "cr", "cy", "cz", "de",
               "dk", "do", "ec", "ee", "es", "fi", "fr", "gr", "gt", "hk",
               "hn", "hu", "id", "ie", "is", "it", "jp", "lt", "lu", "lv",
               "mc", "mt", "mx", "my", "ni", "nl", "no", "nz", "pa", "pe",
               "ph", "pl", "pt", "py", "se", "sg", "sk", "sv", "tr", "tw", "uy"]

#europa=["",]

def TopMundial(df, Top, date, countries):
    #recorrer el vector countries. Por cada pais crear una columna
    for country in countries(59): #(calcula el pais y lo pone en el TopMundial. AQUI TENGO EL PROBLEMA DE CREAR POR CADA PAIS UNA COLUMNA DONDE ESTEN SUS RESPECTIVAS CANCIONES)
        countries[country].append        

        topcountry= TopCountry(df,Top,date,countries[country])
        topcountry.start()
    return TopMundial
print(countries)

#transformar las canciones en valores numericos
#tambien creamos un vector europa con sus respectivos paises y lo llamamos en la funcion TopMundial    
#funcion de correlacion
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow Ludmila! Para que sea más fácil responder a tu pregunta, te recomiendo que completes lo que ya has escrito con una explicación clara de por qué el código que ya tienes no hace lo que quieres. Es decir: ya has explicado cuál es el resultado esperado, pero no nos has dicho en qué falla o qué le falta. Por otro lado, es mejor que reduzcas el ámbito de tu problema y preguntes algo muy concreto, o algunas personas pensarán que "quieres que les hagas el trabajo". ¡Suerte!

Comment: Hola Juan! Muchas gracias por tu recomendación ahora veo cómo explicarlo de manera más específica =)

Comment: Me parece excelente que tengas en cuenta la observación que te hicieron acerca de como preguntar, no estoy seguro donde falla tu código, o si falla, pero veo cosas que quizás no te funcionen adecuadamente, cuando haces esto `df=df[df.region==country]` estas evaluando a un booleano, por lo cual es lo mismo que hacer esto: `df=df[True]` o `df=df[False]`, y eso puede producir errores, también noto que renombras muchas veces las variables de manera innecesaria, y eso también puede generar varios errores en tu código, especifíca más la pregunta, para poder ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias German! Finalmente pude resolverlo, pero hay varias cosas que necesito entender. Próximamente subiré la solución de cada punto. Saludos a todos y gracias por ayudarme =)

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente aquí está el ejercicio resuelto =) Gracias a todos por su colaboración ;)

spotify.py (BD en Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/edumucelli/spotifys-worldwide-daily-song-ranking)

Solución:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

#read csv
sp=pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')

sp.columns=['position','track_name','artist','streams','url','date','region']  ##renombro columnas por comodidad

paises={'es':'España','it':'Italia','cy':'Cipre','ar':'Argentina','al':'Albania',
    'at':'Austria','au':'Australia','be':'Belgica','bo':'Bolivia','br':'Brasil',
    'ca':'Canada','ch':'Suiza','cl':'Chile','co':'Colombia','cr':'Costa Rica',
    'cz':'Republica Checa','de':'Alemania','dk':'Dinamarca','do':'Republica Dominicana',
    'ec':'Ecuador','ee':'Estonia','es':'España','fi':'Finlandia','fr':'Francia',
    'gb':'Gran Bretaña','gr':'Grecia','gt':'Guatemala','hk':'Hong Kong','hn':'Honduras',
    'hu':'Hungria','id':'Indonesia','ie':'Irlanda','is':'Islandia','jp':'Japon','lt':'Lituania',
    'lv':'Letonia','mx':'Mexico','my':'Malasia','nl':'Paises Bajos','no':'Noruega',
    'nz':'Neva Zelanda','pa':'Panama','pe':'Peru', 'ph':'Filipinas', 'pl':'Polonia',
    'pt':'Portugal','py':'Paraguay','se':'Suecia','sg':'Singapur','sk':'Eslovaquia',
    'sv':'El Salvador','tr':'Turquia','tw':'Taiwan','us':'Estados Unidos','uy':'Uruguay','global':'Global'} ##completar el diccionario

#Listado de canciones
songs=sp.track_name.unique()
songs=songs.tolist()

#Como obternet el array countries
#aux=sp.groupby('region').sum().reset_index()
#aux=aux.region.tolist()
countries = ['ar','at','au','be','bo','br','ca','ch','cl','co','cr','cy','cz','de','dk',
 'do','ec','ee','es','fi','fr','gb','global','gr','gt','hk','hn','hu','id','ie','is','it','jp','lt','lv',
 'mx','my','nl','no','nz','pa','pe','ph','pl','pt','py','se','sg','sk','sv','tr','tw','us','uy']


##### Esta funcion permite ver los streams max y min a segunda de la agrupacion
def maxMin(df, gb, mercado):    #df=Dataframe    gb=modo de grupby

    if mercado!=None:
        df=df[df.region==mercado]
        titulo=paises.get(mercado)
        print('--------------',titulo.upper(),'--------------')
    elif mercado==None:
        print('--------------MUNDO--------------')

    df=df.groupby(gb).sum().reset_index()
    df=df.drop('position', 1)
    df=df[df[gb]!='global']

   # print(df)

    print('MAX')
    maxx=df[df.streams==df.streams.max()]
    print(gb,' : ',maxx.iloc[0,0])
    print('streams : ',maxx.iloc[0,1])

    print(30*'-')
    print('MIN')
    minn=df[df.streams==df.streams.min()]
    print(gb,' : ',minn.iloc[0,0])
    print('streams : ',minn.iloc[0,1])


def weeksInTop(df, song, top, country):

    df=df[df.region==country]
    df=df[df.track_name==song]
    df=df[df.position<=top]
    fecha_inicio=datetime.strptime(df.date.min(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    fecha_fin=datetime.strptime(df.date.max(), '%Y-%m-%d')

    date_delta=fecha_fin-fecha_inicio
    weeks=date_delta.days/7.0
    return int(weeks)

def Top(df, top, country, date):
    df=df[df.region==country]
    df=df[df.position<=top]
    df=df[df.date==date]

    return df

def scatterPlot(df, song, country):
    df=sp[sp.region==country]
    df=df[df.track_name==song]
    df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date) # convert the date column to Datetime

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter([x for x in df.date], df.position, marker=".")
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    myFmt = DateFormatter("%m")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    plt.xlim('2017-01-01', '2017-09-1')
    plt.title(song.upper())
    plt.xlabel('Meses')
    plt.ylabel('Posiciones')
    plt.show()


def TopCountry(df, top, country, date):
    top_c=Top(sp , top , country, date)
    top_c=top_c.track_name
    top_c=top_c.to_frame()
    top_c.columns=[country]
    top_c=top_c.reset_index()
    top_c=top_c.drop('index', 1)
    return top_c


def TopWorld(df, top , date, countries=[]):
    top_mundial=pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(0, len(countries)):
        top_country=TopCountry(sp, top, countries[i], date)
        top_mundial=pd.concat([top_mundial, top_country], axis=1)


    return top_mundial


def Matrix4Corr(df, top, date, countries=[]):
    arr_top=[]
    vacios=[]

    for i in range(0, len(countries)):
        top_country=TopCountry(sp, top, countries[i], date)
        top_country=top_country[countries[i]].values
        top_country=tuple(top_country)
        if not top_country:
            vacios.append(countries[i])
        arr_top.append(top_country)

    matrix=pd.Series(arr_top).apply(frozenset).to_frame(name='top')

    for top in frozenset.union(*matrix.top):
        matrix[top] = matrix.apply(lambda _: int(top in _.top), axis=1)


    matrix.index=countries
    matrix=matrix.drop('top', 1)
    for i in range(0, len(vacios)):
        matrix=matrix.drop(vacios[i],0)

    matrix=matrix.transpose()


    return matrix

def betterCorr(x):
    if x>0:
        1-x
    else:
        1+x


#para el mercado mundial
#maxMin(sp,'region',None)   ### track_name, artist, region, date

####Para solo el mercado español
#maxMin(sp,'artist','es')

song='Shape of You'
top=20
country='es'
date='2017-01-01'  ###2017-03-01 existen nans

####TOP por fecha y pais

#a=Top(sp , top , country, date)
#print(song,'-','Semanas en Top',top,' : ', weeksInTop(sp, song, top, country))

#### SCATTERPLOT
#scatterPlot(sp, song, country)

#Lista de canciones Top en un cierto pais

#print(TopCountry(sp, top, country, date))

#Big DataFrame tops por pais
#a=TopWorld(sp, top, date, countries)  ## si hay nan en registros es porque no hay datos en esa fecha


"""
europa=['es','it','fr','gr','al','cy','be','ch','cz','de','dk','ee','fi','gb','hu','ie','is',
    'lt','lv','nl','no','pl','pt','se','sk','tr']

america=['ar','bo','cl','co','cr','do','ec','gt','hn','mx','pa','pe','py','sv','us','uy']

lejos=['es','ar','it','jp','id','au','us']
mat=Matrix4Corr(sp, 5, '2017-01-01', lejos)


corr = mat.corr()

import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(corr, 
            xticklabels=corr.columns.values,
            yticklabels=corr.columns.values)

"""
```

Este es el modelo de regresión Lineal aplicado para las predicciones a largo plazo. En este proyecto se usaron 2 modelos de predicción: el RBF y el lineal. El modelo RBF es útil en este caso para predicciones más inmediatas a corto plazo; es decir, debemos saber qué comportamiento tuvieron las posiciones hasta el día de hoy para predecir el día de mañana; como máximo este modelo neuronal puede predecir hasta 3 días después para tener mayor confianza en el resultado.

```
#1st January 2017 to 17th August 2017
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR


# Load CSV and columns
sp=pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')

sp.columns=['position','track_name','artist','streams','url','date','region'] 

song='Chantaje'
country='es'


df=sp[sp.region==country]
df=df[df.track_name==song]

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date) # convert the date column to Datetime
df.date=df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

X = df['date'].values[:,np.newaxis]  

y = df['position'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, y, color='darkorange', marker='.')

fig.autofmt_xdate()
myFmt = DateFormatter("%m")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)



lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(X, y)

plt.plot(X, lm.predict(X),color='r', label='Linear Model')



fecha='2017-08-18'   ###fecha prediccion
fecha_predict=fecha
fecha_predict=pd.to_datetime(fecha_predict)
fecha_predict=fecha_predict.toordinal()
X_predict = fecha_predict # put the dates of which you want to predict
y_predict = lm.predict(X_predict)
print('Linear Model - ',fecha, song,'Posicion : ',int(y_predict))

mse_lineal=np.mean((y-lm.predict(X))**2)
print('Error cuadratico medio',mse_lineal)

#prediccion modelo rbf
model_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
model_rbf.fit(X, y)
plt.plot(X, model_rbf.predict(X), color='navy', label='RBF model')
y_rbf_predict=model_rbf.predict(X_predict)
print(50*'-')
print('Non-Linear Model - ',fecha, song,'Posicion : ',int(y_rbf_predict))

mse_rbf=np.mean((y-model_rbf.predict(X))**2)
print('Error cuadratico medio',mse_rbf)

plt.title(song.upper())
plt.xlabel('Meses')
plt.ylabel('Posiciones')

plt.show()

plt.scatter(y, lm.predict(X), marker='.') 
plt.scatter(y, model_rbf.predict(X), marker='.') 
plt.xlabel('Posiciones')
plt.ylabel('Posiciones estimadas')
```

Este sería el modelo de entrenamiento para poder verificar el porcentaje de error y de confianza a la hora de realizar las predicciones de las posiciones de las canciones en el ranking de Spotify (ejemplo con la canción "Chantaje"):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import sklearn
from sklearn.svm import SVR


# Load CSV and columns
sp=pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')

sp.columns=['position','track_name','artist','streams','url','date','region'] 

song='Chantaje'
country='es'


df=sp[sp.region==country]
df=df[df.track_name==song]

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date) # convert the date column to Datetime
df.date=df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

X = df['date'].values[:,np.newaxis]  
y = df['position'].values

#### dividir el data sert randomicamente entre train y test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test=sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=5)




lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np

cambio = datos_zoo.tolist()
lista []
y = 0
for y in cambio:
  if y <5:
    y+= 1
    lista.append(y)
  else:
    y-= 2
    lista.append(y)
lista = np.array(lista,int)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una explicación no caería mal